# Unable to clone any git repo even after adding ssh keys

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am trying to clone a repo from github. To do that

1. I have generated a ssh key using: ssh-keygen.
2. Then I added the content of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to my keys in github account.

Even after that I am unable to clone any repo. I am getting following error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

In this regard, I have gone through a few posts here, but unable to fix.

NOTE: This error I am facing even after removing SSH key from my github account.

EDIT: When I am doing "ssh -T git@github.com", I am getting the same error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
```

As suggested in: https://help.github.com/en/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey, while executing following commands:

```
 1. ssh-add -l ==> The agent has no identities.
 2. ssh-add -l -E md5 ==> The agent has no identities.
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this error for one of these 3 reasons:

1. when you have authentication/authorization problems
2. When you have an internet access problem
3. SSh problems

Do the following:

first in your terminal run `ssh -T git@github.com` if you see your GitHub username in response. you know that you are authenticated properly if not...

first check internet access: make sure you can access GitHub by cloning a public repo (any repo) by SSH (not https). if you fail here you have problems with SSH or internet connection

if this step passed, try to clone one of your other **private** repos by ssh. if you failed. you have an authentication problem and your ssh key is wrong. (try again by https and compare the results)

if this step passed, try to clone this repo by https (not ssh). if you failed. you have an authorization problem and you have no access to this repo

Comment: Internet is fine, as I am able to clone the same repo with https

Comment: what is result of running this command inside terminal? `ssh -T git@github.com`

Comment: So have SSH problems... Are you sure SSH port is not closed by a firewall? or your internet provider?

Comment: Yeah I am not getting idea regarding how to fix it ? I have added/deleted ssh keys in my github multiple times.

Comment: You don't have ssh-key problem (at least so far!) you have SSH problem regardless of keys! find a free ssh server and try to connect them. If you don't have any, you can find here: https://shells.red-pill.eu/. this is not a github related issues. this is a SSH related issue. you mis-changed ssh config or your network banned ssh packets

Comment: I am unable to browse the url you have shared. 

To the best of knowledge, I did not change any SSH config. Is there any way I can check 

1. if my ssh config is proper 
2. if the network has banned ssh packet.

Comment: telnet is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions that worked for me was setting ssh config.

1. Create and open config file:
   `sudo nano ~/.ssh/config`
2. Add following lines and save:

```
Host github.com
Hostname ssh.github.com
Port 443
```

3. Try running: `ssh -T git@github.com`

Now you can clone the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on a deivce i hadn't used for a while.
Command ssh -T git@github.com returned: "no such identity: C:\Users\sfolk/.ssh/id_ed25519_*github-account-name-here* No such file or directory"

I did create new keys however; which created the file "id_ed25119"

So to solve this, i renamed the anonymous fie, added "_*github-account-name-here*.
It uses the same SSH key